# Symfony/Silex SecurityServiceProvider: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, forms, symfony, authentication, silex

I follow the [Silex SecurityServiceProvider][1]

[1]: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html step by step, but when I submit the login form, I got the error:

```
Exception in AbstractToken.php line 154:
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

I don't know where this error comes from... I use exactly the same code as the exemple:

controller:

```
$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});
```

view:

```
<form action="{{ path('connexion') }}" method="post">
    {{ error }}
    <input type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <input type="password" name="_password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The first lines of the error:

```
 in AbstractToken.php line 154
at SplObjectStorage->serialize()
at serialize(array(object(User), true, array(object(Role)), array())) in AbstractToken.php line 154
at AbstractToken->serialize() in UsernamePasswordToken.php line 96
at UsernamePasswordToken->serialize()
at serialize(object(UsernamePasswordToken)) in ContextListener.php line 129
at ContextListener->onKernelResponse(object(FilterResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(array(object(ContextListener), 'onKernelResponse'), object(FilterResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher)) in WrappedListener.php line 61
at WrappedListener->__invoke(object(FilterResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(EventDispatcher))
at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(FilterResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(EventDispatcher)) in EventDispatcher.php line 174
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implements \Serializable.

```
class User extends Entity implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
```

According to the doc

```
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html
```